# BLE，ペリフェラルでセントラルのデバイス名を取得する方法

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

[ble_peripheral](https://pub.dev/packages/ble_peripheral/versions)ライブラリのexampleコードと[flutter_blue_plus 1.20.8](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus#android_specific_error)を使用して，BLE通信できるアプリを作っていて，ペアリング機能ではなく，アプリ内で以前接続したことのあるデバイスを保存させる機能を付けたいと考えています．しかし，peripheral側でcentral側のBluetooth名またはデバイス名を取得する方法が分かりません．どなたかご教示お願いいたします．

Comment: そのライブラリに機能があるかどうかは知りませんが、BLEの仕様としてはこんな記事がヒントになるのでは？ [How in a bluetooth connection can the Peripheral get the Central device name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790911/9014308), [Can a BLE peripheral read the Central name before connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75181375/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます．
教えていただいた記事を基にコーディングしてみます．